# What is the most Angular way to test for a click on the body in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a little dropdown directive that I apply to a nav element. I want to close the dropdown if the user clicks anywhere outside the nav element by setting `$scope.menu.visible = false`.

What is the most Angular way to check for a click or keypress on the body element from within an Angular directive?

The directive I have currently looks like this:

```
angular.module('dropdowns', [])
  .directive('dropdown', function () {
    return {
      scope: true,
      link: function (scope, element) {
        var body = angular.element('body');
        var clickOutside = function (e) {
          var target = angular.element(e.target);
          if (!$.contains(element, target)) {
            scope.menu.visible = false;
          }
        }
        body.on('click', clickOutside);
        // body.on('keyup', scope.escapeKey);
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.menu = {visible: false};
        $scope.hide = function () {
          $scope.menu.visible = false;
        };

        $scope.show = function () {
          scope.menu.visible = true;
        };

        $scope.toggle = function (e) {
          $scope.menu.visible = !$scope.menu.visible;
        };

        $scope.escapeKey = function (e) {
          if (e.which === 27) {
            $scope.hide();
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

The dropdown is setup using the following template fragment:

```
<nav dropdown>
  <a ng-click="toggle()">Menu</a>
  <ul ng-show="menu.visible">
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should modify your directive  little in this case. Post its code.

Comment: Hi @dfsq, code posted. As you can see, I'm violating the spirit of "don't select, direct" here by using jQuery to select the body element in my link function.

Comment: How do you use your directive in HTML? How do you open dropdown?

Comment: @dfsq - Good question, I have posted the template. It's standard stuff. I did originally have more in my directive, but when it came to making changes I found that limited my options.

Comment: See the answer of how simple ideal approach is.

Answer (score 2):

Most Angular way: 
Add it to a directive. Example: add click-events attribute to 'body' tag
Something like:

```
angular.module('directive_name', []).directive('clickEvents', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$document',
  function($rootScope, $document) {
    return {
      link: function() {
        $document.bind('click', function(event) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('click', event);
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);

module.directive('directive_name', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$on('click', function(onEvent, clickEvent) {
          scope.clicked = true;
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Oh hey, that is good, then the directive only needs to know about $rootScope, which is a simple DI.

Comment: Sure is, give it a try you ll figure it out :)

Comment: Looking good but personally I'd avoid polluting the $rootScope if I don't have to and use events sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body ng-click="yourFunction()">
```

Seems to be the obvious choice. However, make sure your `ng-app` directive is on `<html>` to have the `<body>` included in the app.

Comment: This works or course, but lacks access to the dropdown $scope, assuming there are multiple dropdowns on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about "the most Angular way", but maybe the easiest.
Say you have something like this in your template.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu keep_open">
    <li>....
```

Then in your directive's `link` or `controller`, just add the following function

```
/*  forces dropdown to remain open until clicked outside the control */
$('.keep_open').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/tj2ljc

---

[image: imgur]

Comment: The downside of stopPropagation is that if I have more than one dropdown (and I do) and I click the second one, the first will remain open.

Comment: No, the other ones will be closed. I edited my answer, see related plunker :)

Answer (score 1):

You implementation looks pretty good, but I'd really look into Bootstrap inplementation of dropdown.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do in your case is to stop event propagation on dropdown directive element level. Body element on its turn will handle click events that makes their way to it. Here is how link function of your directive would look then:

```
link: function(scope, element) {

    var body = angular.element('body');

    body.on('click', function(e) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.menu.visible = false;
        });
    });

    element.on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // body.on('keyup', scope.escapeKey);
},
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/aUrztdwKL4ze4Vt3qihF?p=preview

Comment: It's good, but fails with multiple nav dropdowns, i.e. the clicking one nav element doesn't close other nav elements elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my final code in case it's useful to anyone else. There were some good tips, e.g. broadcasting from the rootScope and using stopPropagation. I ended up with something like this. It will close when any element not contained by the dropdown is clicked on, or the escape key is pressed.

I ended up keeping the reference to body in the closure, so each dropdown keeps it's own reference, it still requires a select, but becomes self contained, which is a bonus.

```
angular.module('dropdowns', [])
  .directive('dropdown', function () {
    return {
      scope: true,
      link: function (scope, element) {

        scope.menu = {
          visible: false
        };

        scope.hide = function () {
          scope.menu.visible = false;
        };

        scope.show = function () {
          scope.menu.visible = true;
        };

        scope.toggle = function (e) {
          scope.menu.visible = !scope.menu.visible;
        };

        var escapeKey = function (e) {
          if (e.which === 27) {
            scope.hide();
            scope.$apply();
          }
        };

        var clickOutside = function (e) {
          if (!$.contains(element[0], e.target)) {
            scope.hide();
            scope.$apply();
          }
        }
        var body = angular.element('body');
        body.on('click', clickOutside);
        body.on('keyup', escapeKey);

      }
    };
  });
```